# Unexpected behaviour xarray Dataset.sel

Tags: python, indexing, dataset, python-xarray

As I understand from the documentation, from an xarray Dataset you can select data based on coordinate values.
However, I now get an error.

I have an xarray Dataset named Data, with these dimensions and coordinates:

```
Dimensions:      (Time: 133, bottom_top: 32, bottom_top_stag: 33, south_north: 75, south_north_stag: 76, west_east: 75, west_east_stag: 76)
Coordinates:
    XLONG        (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 3.9869385 ... 5.0813293
    XTIME        (Time) datetime64[ns] 2018-10-10 ... 2018-10-12T18:00:00
    XLAT_V       (Time, south_north_stag, west_east) float32 52.062534 ... 52.734966
    XLAT         (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 52.067024 ... 52.73047
    XLONG_U      (Time, south_north, west_east_stag) float32 3.9796143 ... 5.088745
    XLAT_U       (Time, south_north, west_east_stag) float32 52.067005 ... 52.73042
    XLONG_V      (Time, south_north_stag, west_east) float32 3.986969 ... 5.081421
```

So I would expect I can do:
`Data.sel(Time=Data.XTIME[0].values)` to obtain all data from time 0.

This yields
`IndexError: index 1539129600000000000 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 133`

However, `Data.sel(Time=0)`  works perfectly fine. I thought this was supposed to be the bahavior of `Dataset.isel()`, not `Dataset.sel()`

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? (And how I can select data based on coordinate values?)

Comment: For `sel` to work, your coordinate would need to have the same name as the dimension.

Comment: @kmuehlbauerL Thank you so much! I must have overlooked that in the documentation..